# Flexpaper Split Page Render Doesn't Work

Tags: flash, flexpaper

I am developing the project which includes documents and showing them to users. I am using flexpaper for showing docs. I have large pdf documents so I convert it to swf format and split per page. For example : Hello World.pdf is my document. I am converting it to Hello World0.swf, Hello World1.swf Hello World2.swf etc.

Ok. Actual problem is when I bring them from server it doesn't comes. Source code is below :

```
        $('#documentViewer').FlexPaperViewer(
        {
            config: {

                SWFFile: 'http://localhost:3201/{ConvertedBooks/1/1/Page[*,1].swf,387}',
                Scale: 0.6,
                ZoomTime: 0.5,
                ZoomInterval: 0.1,
                FitPageOnLoad: false,
                FitWidthOnLoad: false,
                PrintEnabled: false,
                MinZoomSize: 0.2,
                MaxZoomSize: 5,
                localeChain: "en_US",
                jsDirectory: "",
                localeDirectory: "",
                RenderingOrder: "flash"
            }
        }
    );
```

When I am doing this my console has an error :

```
GET http://localhost:3201/%7BConvertedBooks/1/1/Page[*,1].swf,387%7D
```

The request has failure.  I have checked and all the paths are true

Answer (score 0):

Surround the whole url with the brackets, like so:

```
SWFFile: '{http://localhost:3201/ConvertedBooks/1/1/Page[*,1].swf,387}',
```